# angularjs xeditable - show preselected value in editable-select with dynamic data from $http.get

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, x-editable

Why is the Group-Row empty, when i push the Edit Button?
I want to have the same value there from the list, when the Edit Mode is on an the Dropdown is visible.

How can i resolve this?

[click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EhAh.png)

**Please check this Working Code**:

**Here is my [`plnkr`](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ubblfnx0mmAgrFbVAl7Q?p=preview)**

```js
var app = angular.module("employment", ["xeditable"]);
 
 app.run(function(editableOptions) {
   editableOptions.theme = 'bs3'; // bootstrap3 theme. Can be also 'bs2', 'default'
 });

 app.controller('EditableRowCtrl', function($scope, $filter, $http)
 {
  
    $scope.users = [];
    $http.get('userdata.json').success(function(data){
     $scope.users = data;
    });

    $scope.statuses = [
        {value: 1, text: 'aktiv'},
        {value: 2, text: 'inaktiv'}
    ]; 

    $scope.groups = [
        {id: 1, text: 'Administrator'},
        {id: 2, text: 'SuperUSer'},
        {id: 3, text: 'Mitglied'},
    ];     
    
    $scope.showGroup = function(user) {
      if(user.group && $scope.groups.length) {
        var selected = $filter('filter')($scope.groups, {id: user.group});
        return selected.length ? selected[0].text : 'Not set';
      } else {
        return user.groupName || 'Not set';
      }
    };

    $scope.showStatus = function(user) {
      var selected = [];
      if(user.status) {
        selected = $filter('filter')($scope.statuses, {value: user.status});
      }
      return selected.length ? selected[0].text : 'Not set';
    };

    // remove user
    $scope.removeUser = function(index) {
      $scope.users.splice(index, 1);
    };

    // add user
    $scope.addUser = function() {
      $scope.inserted = {
        id: $scope.users.length+1,
        name: '',
        status: null,
        group: null 
      };
      $scope.users.push($scope.inserted);
    };
 });
```

Comment: Please attach the code in here, as it will stay forever alive.

Answer (score 1):

@M1ke, I don't know if you're still working on this.  I just saw this question.  The problem is that your status and group codes are defined as strings in  userdata.json and integers in the statuses and groups objects.  I just changed them to integers in the userdata and it worked like a charm.